# Передача двумерного массива в функцию по ссылкам

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, матрицы

Надо, чтобы функция умножала два двумерных массива. Не принимает.

Комментарий компилятора:

> [Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[size]' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int Umnozhenie(int** Matrix_1, int** Matrix_2, int size, int** Matrix_res);

int main() {

    int size;
    cin>>size;
    system("cls");
    int Matrix_1[size][size];
    int Matrix_2[size][size];
    int Matrix_res[size][size];

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){  
        for(int j=0;j<size; j++){

            Matrix_1[i][j]=(rand() % 10);
            Matrix_2[i][j]=(rand() % 10);
            cout<<Matrix_1[i][j]<<" ";

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){  
        for(int j=0;j<size; j++){

            cout<<Matrix_2[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    Umnozhenie(Matrix_1,Matrix_2,size,Matrix_res);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В языке С++ нет массивов неконстантного размера. Поэтому ваше `in>>size; int Matrix_1[size][size];` уже обречено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дополню предыдущего оратора (да, в целом он придал правильное направление мысли).

Если Вы объявляете массив как статитческий

```
int Matrix_1[size][size];
```

то в объявлении функции должны указывать кроме имени переменной (массива) еще и его размеры. Допускается не указывать одну размерность (внутреннюю, левую). Т.е. объявление функции должно быть для таких массивов:

```
int Umnozhenie(int Matrix_1[][size], int Matrix_2[][size], int size, int Matrix_res[][size]);
```

Очевидно, что так делать глупо, хоть синтаксис и позволяет: таким образом функция не сможет работать с массивами другого размера. Это одна из причин, почему неудобно использовать статические массивы ("многомерные").

Выходов тут может быть несколько. Один (вернее, даже пару) указал ранее
*Pavel Gridin*. Хотя он мог еще и про операторы **new/delete** упомянуть - это же код на С++.

Могу предложить еще более коварный способ, который позволит не переопределять массивы. В функцию можно передавать указатели на первые элементы массивов (**&Matrix[0][0]**), а внутри самой функции работать с такими массивами как с одномерными, но со сложными индексами (типа **Matrix[j + size * i]**, если внешним будет цикл со счетчиком по i). Естественно, тогда в объявлении функции нужно использовать одинарные указатели, а не двойные:

```
int Umnozhenie(int* Matrix_1, int* Matrix_2, int size, int* Matrix_res);
```

Так можно делать по той причине, что такие (статические) массивы в С и С++ в памяти гарантированно выделяются одним куском.

В принципе, немного разобравшись с работой указателей можно сделать внутри функции и конструкцию (переменную-массив) с двумя индексами, но это будет немного сложнее.

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя описывать массив динамически, то есть переменного размера, либо сделайте

```
int **Matrix_1 = (int **)malloc(size * size * sizeof(int));
```

Либо пользуйтесь std:: vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix_1;
```